# Android Connectivity Checker BroadcastReceiver run twice or triple times after Device connected

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, connectivity

I Am using BroadcastReciever to check Connectivity in Android App

In AndroidManifest.xml :

```
    <!-- Connectivity Checker  -->
    <receiver android:name="com.emaarit.app.nikanco.services.NikanReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

BroadcastReciever  Class :

```
public class NiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String TAG = NiReceiver.class.getSimpleName();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        LTH.dLog(TAG, " on Receive : " + context.getString(R.string.app_name)+" , Connected : "+ NetHelpers.connected(context));
    }
}
```

Also `LTH` (Log Tag Helper) is my custom class to Manage Logs, And `dLog` print logs on Debug Level.

When i Turn `wifi` `Off` And `On` Logs Are :

```
01-12 10:47:25.680    D/NiReceiver﹕ on Receive : NiCo , Connected : false
01-12 10:47:30.770    D/NiReceiver﹕ on Receive : NiCo , Connected : false
01-12 10:47:35.819    D/NiReceiver﹕ on Receive : NiCo , Connected : false
01-12 10:47:41.717    D/NiReceiver﹕ on Receive : NiCo , Connected : true
```

And When i Turn `3G` `Off` And `On` Logs Are :

```
01-12 10:52:07.777    D/NiReceiver﹕ on Receive : NiCo , Connected : false
01-12 10:52:17.361    D/NiReceiver﹕ on Receive : NiCo , Connected : true
```

On `wifi` Logcat Shows Triple Messages On Connection Turned `On` or `Off`

Why this Happened ?
How i can fix it ?

Comment: one thing I noticed that when the wifi turns on it shows only one log, i.e., true, so that is correct, but the code checks thrice if not connected/ not turned on, try adding an if else condition for getting logs for both turning on and off of wifi. You will get some clue then I guess..

Answer (score 2):

Your receiver gets called multiple times because you added WIFI_CHANGED and CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE.

Only use CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE and it should be fixed.